# Wordpress, logotype duplicated on iPads

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, ipad

I'm developing this site: esident.logotypefactory.com
Everything is ok on desktops, phones. But when it comes to iPads the logo duplicates or something is wrong...

So try this:

1) Go to esident.logotypefactory.com on your iPad
2) Swipe to the left so the screen goes to the right, you will see the second logotype.

Why does it do like that? What am I doing wrong?

What I want:

1) Have a logo always on the top left side.
2) When you click on the menu, have the logo also there on same place.

What I think:

That the second logo is the logo that should be viewable when you click on the menu. As when you click on the menu, you can't "swipe" to see the second logo.

Please help me guys.

```css
.fusion-header {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden
}
.fusion-header-v2 .fusion-header,
.fusion-header-v3 .fusion-header,
.fusion-header-v4 .fusion-header,
.fusion-header-v5 .fusion-header {
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
}
.fusion-logo {
float: left;
zoom: 1
}
.fusion-logo:before,
.fusion-logo:after {
content: " ";
display: table
}
.fusion-logo:after {
clear: both
}
.fusion-logo a {
display: block
}
.fusion-logo img {
width: auto
}
.fusion-logo-2x {
display: none
}
.fusion-mobile-logo-1x,
.fusion-mobile-logo-2x {
display: none
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
.fusion-standard-logo.fusion-logo-1x {
    display: none
}
.fusion-standard-logo.fusion-logo-2x {
    display: inline-block
}
}
.fusion-secondary-header {
min-height: 43px;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
}
.fusion-secondary-header .fusion-alignleft {
float: left;
margin-right: 0
}
.fusion-secondary-header .fusion-alignright {
float: right;
margin-left: 0
}
.fusion-header-v2 .fusion-secondary-header {
border-top: 3px solid transparent
}
.fusion-secondary-header .fusion-mobile-nav-holder {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto
}
.fusion-header-separator {
padding: 0 6px
}
.fusion-contact-info {
line-height: 43px
}
.fusion-header-v4 .fusion-header {
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px
}
.fusion-header-v4 .fusion-logo {
width: 100%
}
.fusion-header-v4 .fusion-logo a {
float: left
}
.fusion-header-v4 .searchform {
float: right;
margin-left: 15px
}
.fusion-header-v4 .search-table {
width: 286px
}
.fusion-header-tagline {
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 32px;
font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal
}
.fusion-header-banner {
float: right
}
.fusion-logo .fusion-header-banner a {
float: none
}
```

```html
  <div class="fusion-header"><div class="fusion-row"><div class="fusion-logo" data-margin-top="65px" data-margin-bottom="31px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-right="0px"> <a href="http://esident.logotypefactory.com"> <img src="http://esident.logotypefactory.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo.png" width="221" height="51" alt="Esident" class="fusion-logo-1x fusion-standard-logo"> <img src="http://esident.logotypefactory.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo.png" width="221" height="51" alt="Esident" style="width:221px; max-height: 51px; height: auto;" class="fusion-standard-logo fusion-logo-2x"> <img src="http://esident.logotypefactory.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/mobilen-logo.png" alt="Esident" class="fusion-logo-1x fusion-mobile-logo-1x"> <img src="http://esident.logotypefactory.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo.png" alt="Esident" style="max-width:195px; max-height: 47px; height: auto;" class="fusion-logo-2x fusion-mobile-logo-2x"> </a></div><div class="fusion-mobile-menu-icons"><a href="#" class="fusion-icon fusion-icon-bars"></a></div><div class="fusion-mobile-nav-holder"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue with doubled logotype. Also I coudn't find any problem with swiping to the left.

Checked under Safari @ iPad mini@iOS9. Check the screnshot
---> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ln21k0umpaktpeo/image1.PNG?dl=0

- Single logotype on the top left position

Comment: Hi Mike, Try to zoom out on iPad mini.

Comment: You put <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> tag, so Safari doesn't let me use pinch-to-zoom gesture.

Comment: I've just noticed that you made some changes - layout is now broken. Background image doesn't fill entire browser window. In portrait and landscape. Earlier everything looked just fine.